# C++: Why pass-by-value is generally more efficient than pass-by-reference for built-in (i.e., C-like) types

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

just as what indicated in the title

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A compiler vendor would typically implement a reference as a pointer. Pointers tend to be the same size as or larger than many of the built-in types. For these built-in types the same amount of data would be passed whether you passed by value or by reference. *In* the function, in order to get the actual data, you would however need to dereference this internal pointer. This can add an instruction to the generated code, and you will also have *two* memory locations that may not be in cache. The difference won't be much - but it could be measured in tight loops.

A compiler vendor could choose to disregard const references (and sometimes also non-const references) when they're used on built-in types - all depending on the information available to the compiler when it deals with the function and its callers.

Comment: It's worth noting that for inlined functions, pass by reference can sometimes be a fair bit faster than pass by value, since can simply substitute the passed-in lvalue for the parameter.  In some cases, the compiler may be able to substitute pass-by-reference when it couldn't alter the semantics, but knowing when such a substitution could alter code semantics isn't always easy.

Comment: Conversion of `foo(const int &x)` to `foo(int x)` isn't always safe.  If the reference is to a global variable, or something reachable via pointers from global variables, `foo(const int &x){ global = 2; return x;}` should return `2`, not the old value of `x`.  References can go away when inlining, though.  And apparently `gcc -fipa-sra` can sometimes do it for you without inlining: [Performance cost of passing by value vs. by reference or by pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523201)

Answer (score 11):

For pod types like int, char, short, and float the size of the data is the same size (or smaller) than the address passed in to reference the actual data. Looking up the value at the referenced address is an unnecessary step and adds additional cost.

For example, take the following functions `foo` and `bar`

```
void foo(char& c) {...}
void bar(char c) {...}
```

When `foo` is called an address is passed by value of either 32bits or 64bits, depending on your platform. When you use `c` within `foo` you have the cost of looking up the value of data held at the passed in address.

When calling `bar` a value of the size of char is passed in and there is no address lookup overhead.

Comment: Very often the actual passed data for a smaller type would correspond to the CPU's native word size.

Comment: @Erik: and when it doesn't (`char`), isn't it promoted to a wider type (`16` bits) so as to be passed through a register ?

Comment: @Matthieu M.: It's usually promoted to the full size also for registers - on a x86 32 machine it'll be passed in e.g. EAX not AX or AH/AL, EAX is faster. All depending on the compiler of course

Answer (score 5):

In practice, C++ implementations generally implement pass-by-reference by passing a pointer under the hood (assuming the call isn't inlined).

So there's no clever mechanism that will allow pass-by-reference to be faster, since it's no faster to pass a pointer than to pass a small value. And pass-by-value can also benefit from better optimization once you're in the function. For example:

```
int foo(const int &a, int *b) {
    int c = a;
    *b = 2;
    return c + a;
}
```

For all the compiler knows, `b` points to `a`, which is called "aliasing". Had `a` been passed by value, this function could optimize to the equivalent of `*b = 2; return 2*a;`. In a modern CPU's instruction pipeline, this could be more like "start a loading, start b storing, wait for a to load, multiply by 2, wait for b to store, return", instead of "start a loading, start b storing, wait for a to load, wait for b to store, start a loading, wait for a to load, add a to c, return", and you start to see why the potential for aliasing can have a significant effect on performance. In some cases, if not necessarily a huge effect in this one.

Of course aliasing only impedes optimization in cases where it changes the effect of the function for some possible input. But just because your intention for the function is that aliasing shouldn't ever affect the results, it doesn't necessarily mean the compiler can assume it doesn't: sometimes in fact, in your program, no aliasing occurs, but the compiler doesn't know that. And there doesn't have to be a second pointer parameter, any time that your function calls code that the optimizer "can't see", it has to assume that any reference could change.