# How and when does the mem size of a parameter in a function, in c++, will be a concern?

Tags: c++

Recently I received a feedback on a issue with the following warning from a colleague, who uses Coverity, a static analysis tool.

> Passing the value of a large parameter (PASS_BY_VALUE)
> pass_by_value: Passing parameter **parameter_name** of type **class_name** (size 184 bytes) by value, which exceeds the low threshold of 128 Passing parameter

This led me to wonder about how the size of the parameter will affect the quality of the application, and when will it be a major concern if the size of the parameter get out of hand?

And what is a good rule of thumb to keep it in check?

Comment: There can be good reason to pass by value, but for larger objects using a const reference is generally a better idea. There's the cost of copying the object as well as space on the stack for it.

Comment: From the warning message, it appears Coverity considers 128 bytes to be the rule-of-thumb threshold for pass-by-value.

Comment: Depends on the platform where the tipping point is for size of parameters.  Not sure if Coverity is configurable, but on my platform it's 256-512 bytes.  128 bytes would be squawking sooner than I'd be happy with -- but even those (and larger) are worth scrutinizing.  (I use Coverity on my project, but I'm not the admin for it.)

Comment: No general rule of thumb, because the only consistently true answer is "it depends".    This link may be relevant   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185665/performance-cost-of-passing-by-value-vs-by-reference-or-by-pointer/40185996

Comment: 99% of the time, you can and should pass objects by const reference instead of by value. Avoids the overhead of the copy and accomplishes the same thing.  That is prefer `void SomeFunction(const Foo& f)` over `void SomeFunction(Foo f)`

Comment: Thanks, guys! I would think I'm still pretty noob with C++. These comments help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

|  | Pass by value | Pass by reference | Advantage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cost of passing the argument | copy object | copy pointer | by value, if `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(T*)`, by ref, if `sizeof(T) > sizeof(T*)` |
| object access | direct | indirect | by value |
| can alias | no the optimizer can do more access optimizations | yes optimizer is restricted in access optimization | by value |

For object smaller or equal in size to the size of a pointer it's a no brainer: pass by value has no disadvantages compared to pass by ref, only advantages.

As you consider bigger objects the cost of copying will eventually outweigh the disadvantages of pass by ref. Where that line is it's difficult to tell. And that line differs on different architectures and calling conventions. For your environment Coverity draws the line at 128 bytes, which I am sure is arrived at by smart people with experience and from doing relevant tests. You can use that limit, you can use another one if you want or you can profile your application to see what applies to your case.

Comment: Thanks @bolov! This helps demystified some of my thoughts!