# Function Params as 'const T&' and 'T&&'

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue

Need to understand and figure out how to work efficiently with these 2 definitions on lowlevel.

```cpp
void func(const T& foo)
{
    T bar = foo;
}

// Lets overload this
void func(T&& foo)
{
    T bar = foo;
}
```

Here is what I know already.

- `T&& foo` is for rvalue which is not creating copy of your param that you are pass through function. Ex : `func(5)` works nice.
- `const T& foo` is also okay for the rvalue.
- `T&& foo` cannot pass lvalue.

So what is the fundemental reason, whats the main get of differenciates usage? I'm not expecting `const T&` also doesnt create copy for passed param as well. Or is it ? So went to oblivion, need clear answer on this.

Edit : I guess need to do addition. Asked question as `int` but this is mainly valid for any class type which we are going to avoid copies.

Edit : Converting question on generic typename T, to be more certain on questions intentions.

Comment: [C++: **Why pass-by-value is generally more efficient than pass-by-reference for built-in (i.e., C-like) types**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346853/c-why-pass-by-value-is-generally-more-efficient-than-pass-by-reference-for-bu) and [C++11 rvalue reference vs const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104649/c11-rvalue-reference-vs-const-reference)

Comment: *"how to work efficiently with these 2 definitions on lowlevel...."* Not clear what efficiency and lowlevel you're referring to.

Comment: If you want to work efficiently, use `void func(int foo)`.

Comment: Relevant: [What does T&& (double ampersand) mean in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5481539/2402272)

Comment: passing an int is not a very good example of an object with a heavy copy constructor that you would like to avoid, think about `shared_ptr` or a non-copyable widget, or an object that you can't afford to copy.

Comment: @user12002570 efficiency by means storage wise and performance wise.

Comment: @AhmedAEK so one of them avoiding copy ? which one, didnt get it ?

Comment: @OmrumCetin, for fundamental types such as `int`, where you want to accept both rvalue and lvalue arguments and disallow the function modifying the caller's objects, you cannot do better than ordinary pass-by-value (`void func(int foo)`) for either storage or performance.  Rvalue references and `const` lvalue references are interesting only for objects having more complicated structure and semantics.

Comment: @JohnBollinger imagine I only have 8 bytes of ram and 4 of them programming block and 4 bytes of them for stack (usage for single int). Your solution overflows.

Comment: Imagine that an `int` takes 4 bytes of RAM, and a reference takes 8 bytes of RAM plus 4 byte of RAM for the caller's int argument.

Comment: [For pod types like `int, char, short, and float` the size of the data is the same size (or smaller) than the address passed in to reference the actual data. Looking up the value at the referenced address is an unnecessary step and adds additional cost.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346883/12002570)

Comment: @Omrum I've some serious doubts that C++ is a good language choice for a machine with 8 bytes of RAM...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat could we please stick to point? People can write down dozens of arguments here, just I'm trying to narrow scope. Copying implicitly is not an option.

Comment: Nitpicking: For `bar = foo;`, it will be regardless whether `foo` is of type `const int&` or `int&&`. `foo` is an LValue and you have to use at least `bar = std::move(foo);` to enable move-semantic. (...ignoring that it doesn't make sense at all for `int`).

Comment: *What is the main gist that differentiates usage?*  The `Foo&&` parameter is telling the caller "I'm taking ownership of the argument's innards" (leaving the caller with an empty gutted husk, in a valid-but-unspecified state for most `std::` types).  The `Foo const&` parameter is telling the caller "I'm using the argument, but I'm not modifying the argument".  (And `Foo&` parameter tells the caller "I'm modifying the argument, but I'm not taking ownership of it... just borrowing it for a bit".)

Comment: If both overloads do the same things, maybe the rvalue overload would better be removed since a `T &&` can be bound to a `const T &` (which you already know). It would be useful to have it if you want to do something different when you have an rvalue (for example "steal" the data, take ownership, i.e. move-assign it into another object).

Comment: Very good answers guys, but still I'm not sure about its storage usage.

Comment: Whether you accept your parameter through `T &&` or `const T &`, there is no copy made. A reference, no matter how qualified, is still, well... a reference.

Comment: @Fareanor please type it as an answer, thank you.... Thats what I wanted to learn, on the other side of things seems like its how you design your code...

Comment: @OmrumCetin if your storage is so tight that you have to count individual bytes of your function parameters then (1) again, ordinary pass-by-value is better for you for parameters of type `int`, but also (2) C++ is overall heavier than you may realistically be able to afford.

Comment: Yes John, if we think widely. Well known, thanks to you as well.

Comment: @OmrumCetin You're welcome !

Comment: @OmrumCetin No the question is fine. The valid reasons to downvote a question are if the question is either off-topic, or unclear, or if it lacks of research/debugging effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"So what is the fundemental reason, whats the main get of differenciates usage?"*

If both of your overload do **exactly** the same thing, there is no point of having the rvalue-qualified one since a `T &&` can be bound to a `const T &` (and you're already aware of that).

The need to have the rvalue overload is when you need to do something different if an rvalue is passed (for example, move-assign the object into another one or anything else you could think of).

> *"I'm not expecting const int& also doesnt create copy for passed param as well. Or is it ?"*

A reference, no matter how qualified, is still a reference. So whether you accept your argument through a `const T &` or a `T &&`, no copy is made.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that a `template <typename T> void func(T&&)` is a different kind of reference than a non-template `void func(Foo&&)`.  Because that's the way C++ rolls!

Comment: @Eljay You're right. I skipped the perfect-forwading concern because the OP's example does not involve templates (and the question is not about what is `T &&`).

Answer (score 2):

Rvalue references exist to enable move semantics.  For efficiently-copyable types like `int` there is generally no reason to explicitly use an rvalue reference (copying and moving an `int` do the same thing).

Rvalue references are needed to enable move semantics because:

1. You can't tell if a reference-to-const is an rvalue or lvalue
2. You can't modify the object referenced by a reference-to-const to steal the resources it owns

So, as a general rule: use rvalue references when you want to move from an object passed by reference, and use lvalue references-to-const when you don't.