# Can't compile suggested atomic_fetch_max code

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, stdatomic

During [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288936/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text) of my [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/crn7MnW87), reviewer suggested to use `atomic_fetch_max` compatible with the proposal [Atomic maximum/minimum](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0493r1.pdf):

```
template<typename T>
T atomic_fetch_max(std::atomic<T>* obj, typename std::atomic<T>::value_type arg) noexcept
{
    auto prev = *obj;
    while (prev < arg && !obj->compare_exchange_weak(prev, arg)) {}
    return prev;
}
```

instead of my code

```cpp
template<typename T>
void update_max(std::atomic<T>& max_value, T const& value) noexcept
{
    T prev_value = max_value;
    while (prev_value < value && 
           !max_value.compare_exchange_weak(prev_value, value))
    {}
}
```

I tried to incorporate it into my demo and can't make it compiled. Please see the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o964WjrM7).

Two questions here related to the problem:

1. Why the suggested version fails to compile? I can't get the reason from compiler messages (they are too long and I am not sure how to include them here, please update the question if you know the format, I will follow).
2. What is the reason the updated version uses `typename std::atomic<T>::value_type arg` instead of plain `T` or even better `T const &` which makes *arg* referenced value const?

Comment: `T` by value makes sense for any(?) `T` that's worth using with `std::atomic<>`: trivially-copyable and small enough to be lock-free also means it can easily be passed in registers.  You normally want this to inline anyway, but if not, pass by value should be efficient.  Except maybe for objects the size of 2 pointers in some calling conventions.  But most objects you're likely to want `max` on are single numbers, where passing by value is more efficient if there ever is a non-inline function call.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the link has been updated. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterCordes, what do you mean with "T by value" exactly? In the code suggested by the reviewer or in my code? I see it in the review's code only and I don't see this code in the aforementioned proposal, so maybe this is just a mistake from the reviewer. Anyway, key question is why doesn't it compile at all?

Comment: Ah, it doesn't compile because `*obj` produces a `std::atomic<T> &` which is what `auto` picks. https://godbolt.org/z/P4hhTTaYz  They should have used `obj->load()` or better `obj->load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`.  All the other changes, like returning the old value and taking `T` (or `value_type`) by value make sense and seem like improvements to me.  Except for using `...::value_type` instead of `T`, that seems over-complicated especially when they're still just returning a `T`

Comment: I was answering part (2) first, about the non-atomic arg being `T` (by value) or `const T &` (by reference).

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you, you solution worked like a charm! I will remember to check auto in such cases in future. I still have a question on `typename std::atomic<T>::value_type arg` versus `T arg` in this particular case. What for to wrap the type and then take in back from `value_type` instead of using it directly? Is there a special reason for this?

Comment: Apparently yes, see https://wg21.link/P0558R1 and the updated list of duplicates.  (Took me a while to find one for why `T` instead of `T const&`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, amazing, thank you. I got the answer to my question as "*disabling type deduction on the second parameter*", but now I am intrigued by your "Took me a while to find one for why T instead of T const&". Could you please pinpoint the answer, because I failed to find it in this document.

Comment: A couple of the answers on [C++: Why pass-by-value is generally more efficient than pass-by-reference for built-in (i.e., C-like) types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5346853) say similar things to my very first comment, about why `T` instead of `T const &`.  (Or `value_type` instead of `value_type const&`).  Instead of editing the duplicate list twice for this question, I waited until I'd found that Q&A as well as the one about P0558R1.

Comment: @PeterCordes, interesting, thank you. Another question related to this topic (passing by value) and the [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/288936/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text) I started this question from, is *returning* by value. In the code review question in code I asked is it fine to return `std::vector` relying on copy elision or this is not the case and I must do something "more traditional" like passing a reference to a vector which must be created in main()?

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine to return a `std::vector` by value in cases where the callee has to figure out what size to allocate.  For repeated calls, an API where the caller passes a non-const reference to an existing vector (which you resize and overwrite the constents) can be cheaper than creating a new vector for every call, since those have to get destroyed, too.  But that's because you make it impossible to reuse existing storage, not because of copying while returning.  (`vec = foo(...);` can't AFAIK steal the storage from the old `vec` to replace the new vector you return.)

Comment: I see, thank you. Still have some questions on this, but I would rather create a new question (if looking in other sources won't answer them).